# case statement in where clause to return results set include nulls

Tags: oracle

im doing a jasper report that filters by multiple parameters which are optional using a case statement in the where clause. if the parameter is not entered i want results set to satisfy the other parameters also include nulls.

I did a case statement in the where clause.Excluding my last condition i get the results i want. when the param is empty i want the other conditions to b satisfied in result including null records which are satisfied by the other condition in the where clause

```
SELECT
cert.ice_certificate_date_issued AS "START_DATE",
cert.ice_current_license_expiry AS "END_DATE",
--licence_type,
ib.name AS "SHOP",
cert.ice_license_fee AS "SUPERMARKETPRICE",
dist.name AS "DISTRICT",
,iba.ice_price)
,0) AS "ACTIVITY_PRICE",
(select nvl(sum(taxamt),0) from c_ordertax where c_order_id = cert.c_order_id) AS "TAXAMT"
FROM icp_certificate cert
LEFT JOIN c_order ord ON cert.c_order_id = ord.c_order_id
LEFT JOIN icp_business ib ON cert.ice_foreign_trx_entity_id = 
ib.icp_business_id
LEFT JOIN c_bpartner cbp ON cert.c_bpartner_id = cbp.c_bpartner_id
LEFT JOIN c_bpartner_location cbpl ON cert.c_bpartner_id = 
cbpl.c_bpartner_id
LEFT JOIN icp_district dist ON cbpl.ice_district_id = 
dist.ice_district_id
LEFT JOIN c_location loc on ib.c_location_id = loc.c_location_id
LEFT JOIN icp_business_activity_link ibal ON ib.icp_business_id = 
ibal.icp_business_id
LEFT JOIN icp_business_activity iba ON ibal.icp_business_activity_id = 
iba.icp_business_activity_id
WHERE
cert.ad_client_id = 1000555 AND
cert.ad_org_id = 2010520 AND
cert.icp_certificate_status = '01' AND
cert.isactive = 'Y' AND
cert.ice_certificate_type = '0051' AND
cert.ice_currentcertificate = 'Y' AND
cert.icp_certificate_date_issued BETWEEN '01-JAN-19' AND '23-MAY-19' AND
ib.ICp_District_ID = CASE WHEN 0>0 THEN 46445665 else ib.ICp_District_ID 
END
```

--i want the else part to include record where ib.ICp_District_ID  is null

return result of everything that is within the other conditions including records with district id  as a null

Comment: What's the point of `WHEN 0>0`? That's always false.

Comment: Hi its when param>0  it goes to the THEN section but i just put 0>0 for now to test for the else section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you can use

```
.
.
.
(ib.ICp_District_ID = CASE
                        WHEN 0>0 THEN 46445665
                        else ib.ICp_District_ID 
                      END
 OR
 ib.ICp_District_ID IS NULL)
```

which can be simplified to

```
NVL(ib.ICp_District_ID, -99) = NVL(ib.ICp_District_ID, -99)
```

because the CASE expression will always return `ib.ICp_District_ID`. It can be further simplified by just leaving out the condition which checks `ib.ICp_District_ID` completely, because it will always be satisfied. (Assuming, of course, that you intend to leave the condition `WHEN 0 > 0` in place in the CASE expression, which is always FALSE, so it will always fall through to the ELSE).

Best of luck.

Comment: Hi Bob Jarvis wow thankx so much the first option worked. Would like to understand the simplified one also.

Comment: `WHEN 0>0` is always false, so the `CASE` expression always returns `ib.ICp_District_ID`. Thus, the first case is really `(ib.ICp_District_ID = ibICp_District_ID OR ib.ICp_District_ID IS NULL)`, which will always be TRUE. The second case basically says "Compare ib.ICp_District_ID to itself, unless ib.ICp_District_ID is NULL, in which case substitute -99 for the NULLs and compare -99 to -99 (always equal)". So the second case will always return TRUE. So since either case 1 or case 2 will always return TRUE, we don't really need to do this check at all because it won't filter out any results.